# How to hide/Encrypt view Source from Web Page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, web

There is whiteHat(hacker) security scan ran in our Project and they ask us block sensitive data from View Page source, Data like Account number, SSN number

So I have done my R & D on net and found that there is no Direct solution for this thing.

I don't want to disable right click

Does anybody have idea how we can achieve this ?

details :

1. Application - Web
2. Framework - Struts1.X

Comment: Your research didn't lie. Whatever you're trying to display on a web page is also visible within source code. There are stupid tricks to fool the casual viewer, but anyone who's serious about scraping sensitive data won't be fooled. If you want to protect that data, you shouldn't display it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on the client, it's available. Full-stop. You can try to mask it, but that's just security through obfuscation, which isn't security.

If you are looking to block sensitive data, you need to prevent the data from getting to the client in the first place.

If the client needs that data for some reason, then you won't be able to properly hide it.

If you are dealing with things like SSN numbers, usually you won't display the whole SSN on the site. If you only display the last four digits, be sure to only send the last four digits. This is part of data minimization.

You might need to change things so instead of doing calculations on the front-end/client-side, you do them on the server and only spit out the minimum data needed.